# Unable to install CORBA for Eclipse "An error occurred while installing the items..."

Tags: eclipse, installation, corba

I'm trying to install EclipseCORBA.

I'm using the **Install New Software** wizard with the URL

```
http://eclipsecorba.sf.net/update
```

[image: Eclipse Install New Software CORBA]

When it finishes, I get this error message:

[image: Eclipse CORBA Error]

Does anyone have any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same error, also with **4.5** (Mars).

[Another installation guide](http://users.encs.concordia.ca/~h_iraj/comp6231/install_corba_in_eclipse/) pointed me to the development version at `http://eclipsecorba.sourceforge.net/update_unstable`, which did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which Eclipse version you're running, but I'm having the same problem on 4.5 (Mars).

Looking at the CORBA support project page, it hasn't been updated since 2008. Even more, it relies on [OpenORB](http://openorb.sourceforge.net/) 1.4.0 which is unmaintained since 2005.

So the plug-in most probably targets Eclipse **3.4** (*Ganymede*) or **3.3** (*Europa*). Unless you're able to install the plug-in into Eclipse 3.x, I believe you're out of luck.